# Angularjs: How to filter selected fields from an object array

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have an object array like this

```
peoples = [{name:"Joe",age:21,sex:'M'},
{name:"Smith",age:18,sex:'M'},{name:"Sally",age:25,sex:'F'}];
```

Some of these fields are irrelevant so I need to remove attribute age and sex from all of above objects.

This is the desired output.

```
 [{name:"Joe"},{name:"Smith"},{name:"Sally"}];
```

**Update:**
 It would be nice if I can use angularjs inbuilt service like $filter.

Comment: are you trying to get the output after submit from a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't see the need to remove the unnecessary objects since you only access the fields you want. Otherwise you can create a new array from the one you have created chucking out what you don't want.

```
var peoples = [{name:"Joe",age:21,sex:'M'},{name:"Smith",age:18,sex:'M'},{name:"Sally",age:25,sex:'F'}];
var names = [];
peoples.forEach(function(entry) {
    names.push({name:entry.name});
});
console.log("New Names:",names); //[{name:"Joe"},{name:"Smith"},{name:"Sally"}];
```

Comment: I need them to send over http. I need to save some bandwidth here :). While your answer is working and a correct answer, It would be nice if I can use angularjs inbuilt service like $filter.

Comment: This is the correct answer, based on what you asked for the data being sent over http will be EXACTLY the same as what you wanted. If you were to write a filter, it would look almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
   for( var i = 0; i < peoples.length; ++i ) {
             delete peoples[i].age;
             delete peoples[i].sex;
   }
```

`delete` is the keyword created for this